# How to compare two excel sheets

Tags: java, vba, excel, apache-poi

I have two excel files and I need to compare them.

Main case is that the user downloads the file, makes some changes, and uploads it back. After that the system compare them and show a discrepancy report.

I use Apache POI, and I try to understand how track some user actions. E.g. user rename all the cells in a row, then moves it up. How to track these changes?

The problem is if I compare the new file with his last copy it looks like the user deleted one row and created another, instead of renaming and moving it.

I have read that Excel can track user [changes](https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-us/article/Track-changes-in-a-shared-workbook-951bdf89-9ee6-4777-b31e-33ad0f594d18?CorrelationId=2cfa97f9-b784-4dc5-9e38-d672babb702b&ui=en-US&rs=en-001&ad=US) and can create change logs but I don't find any mentions of this feature in POI. This is one idea how to solve this problem, but I think it's not a good one.

So what is the best way to handle these user actions?

Answer (score 1):

In the file I am comparing only first column remove this line

```
if (cell1.getColumnIndex() == 0)
```

try to modification as per our requirement

```
public class ReadWriteXLImple {
    static Boolean check = false;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

        try {

            ArrayList arr1 = new ArrayList();
            ArrayList arr2 = new ArrayList();
            ArrayList arr3 = new ArrayList();

            FileInputStream file1 = new FileInputStream(new File(
                    "src\\file\\Book1.xls"));

            FileInputStream file2 = new FileInputStream(new File(
                    "src\\file\\Book2.xls"));

            // Get the workbook instance for XLS file
            HSSFWorkbook workbook1 = new HSSFWorkbook(file1);
            HSSFWorkbook workbook2 = new HSSFWorkbook(file2);

            // Get first sheet from the workbook
            HSSFSheet sheet1 = workbook1.getSheetAt(0);
            HSSFSheet sheet2 = workbook2.getSheetAt(0);

            // Compare sheets

            // Get iterator to all the rows in current sheet1
            Iterator<Row> rowItera`enter code here`tor1 = sheet1.iterator();`enter code here`
            Iterator<Row> rowIterator2 = sheet2.iterator();

            while (rowIterator1.hasNext()) {
                Row row = rowIterator1.next();
                // For each row, iterate through all the columns
                Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();

                while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {

                    Cell cell = cellIterator.next();

                    // This is for read only one column from excel
                    if (cell.getColumnIndex() == 0) {
                        // Check the cell type and format accordingly
                        switch (cell.getCellType()) {
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                            System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                            arr1.add(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                            break;
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                            arr1.add(cell.getStringCellValue());
                            System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue());
                            break;
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                            arr1.add(cell.getBooleanCellValue());
                            System.out.print(cell.getBooleanCellValue());
                            break;
                        }

                    }

                }

                System.out.println(" ");
            }

            file1.close();

            System.out.println("-----------------------------------");
            // For retrive the second excel data
            while (rowIterator2.hasNext()) {
                Row row1 = rowIterator2.next();
                // For each row, iterate through all the columns
                Iterator<Cell> cellIterator1 = row1.cellIterator();

                while (cellIterator1.hasNext()) {

                    Cell cell1 = cellIterator1.next();
                    // Check the cell type and format accordingly

                    // This is for read only one column from excel
                    if (cell1.getColumnIndex() == 0) {
                        switch (cell1.getCellType()) {
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                            arr2.add(cell1.getNumericCellValue());
                            System.out.print(cell1.getNumericCellValue());
                            break;
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                            arr2.add(cell1.getStringCellValue());
                            System.out.print(cell1.getStringCellValue());
                            break;
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                            arr2.add(cell1.getBooleanCellValue());
                            System.out.print(cell1.getBooleanCellValue());
                            break;

                        }

                    }
                    // this continue is for
                    // continue;
                }

                System.out.println("");
            }

            System.out.println("book1.xls -- " + arr1.size());
            System.out.println("book1.xls -- " + arr2.size());

            // compare two arrays
            for (Object process : arr1) {
                if (!arr2.contains(process)) {
                    arr3.add(process);
                }
            }
            System.out.println("arr3 list values - = - = + " + arr3);
            writeStudentsListToExcel(arr3);

            // closing the files
            file1.close();
            file2.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    // write into new file excel

    private static void writeStudentsListToExcel(ArrayList arr3) {

        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(
                    "D:/Test/output/result.xls");

            HSSFWorkbook workBook = new HSSFWorkbook();
            HSSFSheet spreadSheet = workBook.createSheet("email");
            HSSFRow row;
            HSSFCell cell;
            // System.out.println("array size is :: "+minusArray.size());
            int cellnumber = 0;
            for (int i1 = 0; i1 < arr3.size(); i1++) {
                row = spreadSheet.createRow(i1);
                cell = row.createCell(cellnumber);
                // System.out.print(cell.getCellStyle());
                cell.setCellValue(arr3.get(i1).toString().trim());
            }
            workBook.write(fos);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    // end -write into new file
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do this via Apache, but I know under the review tab in Excel there is an option to track changes, but it needs to be enabled first. Its a robust feature that tells you who, when, and what. It would require you to use the excel sheet (which can also be set to share mode) for review of these changes, but you would only need the one sheet versus an old copy and a new copy.